# Join using Linq failing with Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linqpad

I'm having trouble running a join linq query against EF 4.0. Below is the code, stripped of all unnecessary statements, still reproducing the error)

```
using (var threadRepo = new Repo<Thread>())
using (var postRepo = new Repo<Post>())
{
    var query = threadRepo
                    .Join(postRepo, t => t.PostId, s => s.Id, (t, s) => 1);

    var array = query.ToArray();
}
```

Repo is my implementation of the repository pattern, and the join method looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TInner, TKey, TResult>(
        IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> outerSelector, 
        Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerSelector, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TInner, TResult>> result)
{
    return _objectSet.Join(inner, outerSelector, innerSelector, result);
}
```

The error I get is

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Post'. 
Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') 
are supported in this context.
```

The same query works in LinqPad against the same database (though offcourse, there is not EF 4.0 there)

```
from t in Thread
join p in Post on t.PostId equals p.Id
select 1
```

Any clues on why Linq is giving me this exception?

**Update**

Based on a suggestion below, I tried using a common datacontext for both the repositories using a unit of work. However that doesn't seem to fix the issue. Below is the code I used

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork<CommunicationEntities>())
{
    using (var threadRepo = new Repo<Thread>(uow))
    using (var postRepo = new Repo<Post>(uow))
    {
        var query = threadRepo
                        .Join(postRepo, t => t.PostId, s => s.Id, (t, s) => 1);

        var array = query.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This gives me the same error as before.

Thanks
Jaspreet

Comment: Is `sparkRepo` the same as `postRepo`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake I have seen is that the data context is on the repository level and each repository uses a different data context - in this case that would explain the error. Instead your repositories all should share the same data context using the Unit of Work pattern.

Comment: Cool... I should be able to try that out pretty easily as I have implemented UoW also. Will report back to let you know if that worked.

Comment: Tried that but doesn't seem to work. I have updated the question with the code I used.

Comment: it might not have solved the problem but it is definitely a requirement for this to work. Most likely the other problem is in your repository layer itself, i.e. I can see you are using `IEnumerable` where it should be `IQueryable` - this is tough to get right and not worth the effort with EF (imo) since EF already provides an abstraction for you.

Comment: Did you mean to say that I should be using IQueryable in the Repository's Join method? Also is the alternative to this, using the navigation properties on the entities? Any advantages/disadvantages to each approach?

Comment: @floatingfrisbee: Just glancing at it I would expect the first param to be `IQueryable<TInner> inner` - but I might be wrong, tough to see just looking at this extract.

Comment: You must use `IQueryable` otherwise you will pull all data from both tables to your app. and perform the join in the memory of your app. server. You cannot perform linq-to-entities join on navigation properties. That requires different approach which usually breaks any dreams about generic repository because it requires heavy usage of EF specific features.